# Kohana 3 experts, handling request arguments Route::set(), request->params() in K3 v. >= 3.1

Tags: kohana-3, function-calls

Originally in Kohana 3 you were able to pass controller action arguments/parameters through URL as in:

```
http:/website/controller/actionname/param1/param2/.../paramX
```

and handle it by simply defining the action as in:

```
public action_actionname($params)
{
   $params_array = explode("/", $params); 
   //you can now use $params_array[0], $params_array[1], ...
}
```

Now it seems that since v3.1 they decided to deprecate this feature (here is the [link](http://dev.kohanaframework.org/issues/3536)) and it should be eliminated in v3.2

And it seems they want you to use **Route::Set()** and **request->param()** methods instead. Does this mean that every time you define a method/action in a controller, you have to define a separate routing for each argument someplace else in your application?
 Can anyone please explain to me how this works in simple terms. It just seems like a lot of unnecessary "hassle" to do all of that to simply call a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should consider using the regex param in your route to override the default matching behavior... I typically use this to capture multiple URL parameters in one KO3 "param".  Example:

```
Route::set('route1', '<controller>/<action>(/<param_list>)', array('param_list'=>'.*'))
->defaults(array(
    'controller'   => 'my_default_controller',
    'action'       => 'my_default_index'
));
```

Now in your controller, `$this->request->param("param_list")` will equal whatever matches the regex expression `.*` which means you can capture the rest of the URL just like you were hoping, with slashes and all!

Comment: I had it setup this way too (except the **request->param()**) part, which is how I was able to pass multiple parameters before. I set this **Route::Set()** in the **bootstrap.php** a while ago and have completely forgot about it and I was thinking it was the K3's default setup. I also came to this **request->param()** solution just like you pointed out. So I guess that solves my problem, but I will still go ahead and accept your answer for being the correct one! If only I can get my head around routing of subrequests in HMVC now..., but that's a different set of questions. Thank you! :)